# How can I inject a type into a function in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have this function:

```
elem = (arr, property, num) => {
    arr.forEach(function (elem, index) {
        if (elem[property] === num)
            return elem;
    })
};
```

Is there some way with generics that I can make it so the function can be called along with a `type` so that it returns a specific `type`

For example:

```
exam = <IExam> elem(exams, 'abc', 3);
```

I think this will work but I wonder if I could pass in `IExam` into the function somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be the answer *(there is [a working example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=interface%20IExam%20%7B%0A%09ID%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0Avar%20arr%3A%20any%5B%5D%20%3D%20%20%5B%7B%7D%2C%20%7BID%3A1%7D%2C%20%7BID%3A%202%7D%5D%3B%0A%0Avar%20elem%20%3D%20%3CT%3E(arr%2C%20property%2C%20num)%20%3A%20T%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%09var%20result%3A%20T%20%3D%20null%3B%0A%09%0A%20%20%20%20arr.forEach(function%20(elm%2C%20index)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(elm%5Bproperty%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20num)%0A%09%09%09result%20%3D%20%3CT%3Eelm%3B%0A%09%09%09return%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%0A%09%0A%09return%20result%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Avar%20myResult%3A%20IExam%20%3D%20elem%3CIExam%3E(arr%2C%20%22ID%22%2C%201)%3B%0A%0Avar%20resultPre%20%20%3D%20document.createElement('pre')%3B%0AresultPre.innerText%20%3D%20JSON.stringify(myResult)%3B%0A%0Adocument.body.appendChild(resultPre)%3B%0A))*

```
interface IExam {
    ID: number;
}
var arr: any[] =  [{}, {ID:1}, {ID: 2}];

var elem = <T>(arr, property, num) : T => {
    var result: T = null;

    arr.forEach(function (elm, index) {
        if (elm[property] === num)
            result = <T>elm;
            return;
    })

    return result;
};

var myResult: IExam = elem<IExam>(arr, "ID", 1);
```

and here we can test it *(check the [playground, click run](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=interface%20IExam%20%7B%0A%09ID%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0Avar%20arr%3A%20any%5B%5D%20%3D%20%20%5B%7B%7D%2C%20%7BID%3A1%7D%2C%20%7BID%3A%202%7D%5D%3B%0A%0Avar%20elem%20%3D%20%3CT%3E(arr%2C%20property%2C%20num)%20%3A%20T%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%09var%20result%3A%20T%20%3D%20null%3B%0A%09%0A%20%20%20%20arr.forEach(function%20(elm%2C%20index)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(elm%5Bproperty%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20num)%0A%09%09%09result%20%3D%20%3CT%3Eelm%3B%0A%09%09%09return%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%0A%09%0A%09return%20result%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Avar%20myResult%3A%20IExam%20%3D%20elem%3CIExam%3E(arr%2C%20%22ID%22%2C%201)%3B%0A%0Avar%20resultPre%20%20%3D%20document.createElement('pre')%3B%0AresultPre.innerText%20%3D%20JSON.stringify(myResult)%3B%0A%0Adocument.body.appendChild(resultPre)%3B%0A))*:

```
var resultPre  = document.createElement('pre');
resultPre.innerText = JSON.stringify(myResult);

document.body.appendChild(resultPre);
```